# Trying to handle captcha validation from server side using flask

Tags: python, validation, flask, captcha, server-rendering

here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CAPTCHA Challenge</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #captcha-container {
        width: 250px;
        height: 150px;
        position: relative;
      }
      #captcha-text {
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
      #captcha-box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 80%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      #captcha-input {
        width: 194px;
        height: 46px;
        border: none;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      #captcha-submit {
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>CAPTCHA Challenge</h1>
    <p>To prove that you are human, please solve the following challenge:</p>
    <div id="captcha-container">
      <div id="captcha-text"></div>
    </div>
    <form id="captcha-form" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('captcha') }}">
      <div id="captcha-box">
        <input id="captcha-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter code here" name="code">
        <br>
        <button id="captcha-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <p id="captcha-message"></p>
    <script>
      // Generate a random 4-digit code
      var code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
      var colors = ['#FF4136', '#0074D9', '#2ECC40', '#FFDC00', '#FF851B', '#B10DC9'];
      var colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
      var color = colors[colorIndex];
      var captchaText = document.getElementById('captcha-text');
      captchaText.innerText = code;
      captchaText.style.color = color;
      // Check if the user input matches the code
      var captchaForm = document.getElementById('captcha-form');
      captchaForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var captchaInput = document.getElementById('captcha-input');
        var message = document.getElementById('captcha-message');
        if (captchaInput.value == code) {
          // Submit the form
          captchaForm.submit();
        } else {
          message.innerText = 'Sorry, that was incorrect. Please try again.';
          message.style.color = 'red';
          // Generate a new code and update the CAPTCHA
          code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
          colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
          color = colors[colorIndex];
          captchaText.innerText = code;
          captchaText.style.color = color;
          captchaInput.value = '';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my flask main.py to handle but is not working please someone help

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('captcha.html')

@app.route('/captcha', methods=['POST'])
def captcha():
    code = request.form['code']
    if code == session['captchaInput']:
        return render_template('success.html')
    else:
        return render_template('captcha.html')
```

I want my Flask code to validate the captcha is correct and redirect to successful.html without the user bypassing the captcha I don't want to use JavaScript redirects because it will expose my redirect URL when viewed on the source code.